# React Production Build with Testing Library Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

Do `__snapshots__` folders end up in a React production build? I don't think they do, but I'm not positive. I can't seem to find anything on this.

Comment: technically that depends on how you have your bundler configured. but no, not unless you're doing something really weird.

Comment: That was my thought. I'm using Create React App. I assume they have it configured to ignore __snapshot__ folders.